# JQuery Minus Plugin

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-plugins

I´m searching for a JQuery Plugin that shows me some values in a list and lets me delete from this list again.

Already searched a lot in Google, but haven´t found anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Append to a list:

```
$('#yourSelectList').append('<option value="55">A title</option>');
```

Delete a value:

```
$('#yourSelectList option[value="55"]').remove();
```

Or did you look for something else?